# Powershell form stops responding at near end of script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am testing in a RDP environment with constricted users rights on Windows Server 2008 R2. The script is built as PowerShell Forms V3 (Win64) using Sapien PowerShell studio. I can not debug the program because of this and how applications are put onto each users desktops. I can debug and run locally and everything works 100% fine.

I pull the data from the text boxes send it to the function to do all of the important bits.

`GoTo_Run` sends it to `Get_Credentials` which (aptly named) gets the user credentials that I need. I thought the server was having trouble processing the loops or was just being slow, so I added pauses to help things catch up. I do not believe that to be the case. If Explorer++ isn't running it means the credentials weren't authorized correctly. While it is opened it does some waiting until Exp++ is closed and then opens up and tells them the stuff they've done has been recorded.

The code gets to the part where explorer++ is running and then from there I don't know where it dies. When I go to exit Exp++ I do not receive the final message box at the end of the script and myexe.exe (the name of the overarching script) has stopped responding.

I have already looked through the Sapien Forums at these links:

https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2339

https://www.sapien.com/blog/2011/07/15/primalforms-2011-creating-responsive-loops/

https://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/05/16/powershell-studio-creating-responsive-forms/

Relevant Code:

```
$buttonENTER_Click = {
    $newuser = $username.Text
    $newpass = $password.Text

    GoTo_Run $newpass $newuser
}

function GoTo_Run($newuser, $newpass)
{
    Get_Credentials $newuser $newpass
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
    $exp = Get-Process Explorer++ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if(-not $exp)
    {
        Start-Process '\\this\isthe\filepath'
        Start-Process '\\this\isthe\filepatheroonie'
    }
    while (get-process | ?{ $_.path -eq "\\the\file\path\for\explorer++" })
    {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    }
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Any Changes made have been recorded. If you have any issues or would like something added please email myemail@myemail.edugovorg", "Status")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following .NET Line in your code, `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Any Changes made have been recorded. If you have any issues or would like something added please email myemail@myemail.edugovorg", "Status")`
At the same time you are missing .NET Binding to PowerShell, `[CmdletBinding()]`

Now I have not got much experiance with Sapien PowerShell Studio but I do remember having issues with .NET Binding when compling to EXE in PowerShell Studio.

Without looking at a PowerShell Transcript or PowerShell Event logs, it would not surprise me if this is where you are seeing the script fail / crash.
Have you considered PowerShell native options? `$Error` or `Start-Transcript` and in PowerShell v3+ (Your WMF 3.0?) even `try { }; catch { }`

Using `$Error.Clear()` at the start of the script you can then call the `$Error` log to view more information, let us know if you still need assistance after gaining the built in error logging data.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply jaradsc, could you let me know how you would go about adding the .NET binding to PowerShell?

Comment: Hi Bridger, there is a good review of this here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx and also many more if you Google it. But this is common if you want to call C# (.cs) code or files, Use .NET reference or use (x)AML in your powershell. Your reference to Windows Forms Message box is using a Windows DLL and therefor needs to be imported to PowerShell, Other option is to use a COM Object Referance like 'New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell' for a message box.